# withhold current user from an index of all users in a ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working away at one of my first Ruby on Rails CRUD type apps.

It is an Instagram like application with users accounts (Devise) and pictures uploaded and owned by users.

I would like to create an index of users, a Discover Other Users feature. I have done this, but the output includes the currently logged in User. I wish to omit the current user from the index of users under Discover Other Users.

User Controller Code with the code I tried, unsuccessfully, commented out.

```html
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def new
 end

 def index
  @users = User.all
  #@users = User.where("user_id != ?", current_user.id)
 end
end
```

User View Code

```html
<div class="booyah-box col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
 <%= link_to public_profile_path(user) do %>
 <%= image_tag user.avatar, :class => "smallPlate" %>
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

and the Error

```html
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Users#index
Showing /vagrant/src/platewarz/app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #2 raised:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "user_id" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (user_id != 9)
                                              ^
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (user_id != 9)
Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3
4
5
          
  <div class="booyah-box col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
   <%= link_to public_profile_path(user) do %>
   <%= image_tag user.avatar, :class => "smallPlate" %>
   <% end %>

Rails.root: /vagrant/src/platewarz

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/users/index.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb___484529272__626771048'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails 4:

```
@users = User.where.not(id: current_user.id)
```

else

```
 @users = User.where('id != ?', current_user.id)
```

Something off the topic:

```
Better create a scope in your 
  #user.rb: 
   scope :all_except_current, ->(user) { where.not(id: user) }

 #now use this scope in your controller & get all your users except current_uesr 
 def index 
   @users = User.all_except_current(current_user)  
 end
```

Comment: This answer is correct, I would just suggest that you check if current_user exists. I don't see a before_filter or anything that would guarantee existence of current_user.

Comment: I think, if we define it by scope(check in my model code), we even don't need to verify presence of current_user. Even it's nil, this scope will return all the users.

Comment: Yes! That did it. So I suppose this has to do with version? (I am using Rails 4.2.0). I'm a bit thrown off because a similar scenario, in the same app (Discover Photos) worked with this code:@Pics = Pic.where('id != ?', current_user.id), but my user scenario did not. However, both scenarios work with the suggested .where.not..... Thanks for the help!